# Drop markers at location as "breadcrumbs"/Create route - Google Maps API v3.exp

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm creating an ios app to scout locations "on the go" and mark the locations one by one by clicking a button, and dropping a marker based on current location. I then want to be able to connect the dots, as it were, and create a trail that traverses them all. 
I can drop a marker at my location, and I can tap a bunch of markers onto the map, but I'm having trouble bridging the two. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#add_a_polyline) are just the thing you're looking for. Though, its best for you to save the coordinates in order for you to properly set the trail.

Comment: POLYLINES! I thought so. This is great. Thank you!